# DataGrid calculate difference between values in two databound cells

Tags: wpf, datagrid, binding

In my small application I have a DataGrid (see screenshot) that's bound to a list of Measurement objects. A Measurement is just a data container with  two properties: Date and CounterGas (float).
Each Measurement object represents my gas consumption at a specific date.

[image]

The list of measurements is bound to the DataGrid as follows:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Measurements}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
             <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Path=Date, StringFormat={}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}}" />
             <DataGridTextColumn Header="Counter Gas" Binding="{Binding Path=ValueGas, StringFormat={}{0:F3}}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Well, and now my question :)
I'd like to have another column right next to the column "Counter Gas" which shows the difference between the actual counter value and the last counter value.

E.g. this additional column should calculate the difference between the value of of Feb. 13th and Feb. 6th => 199.789 - 187.115 = 15.674

What is the best way to achieve this? I'd like to avoid any calculation in the Measurement class which should just hold the data. I'd rather more like the DataGrid to handle the calculation.
So is there a way to add another column that just calculates the difference between to values? Maybe using some kind of converter and extreme binding? ;D

P.S.: Maybe someone with a better reputation could embed the screenshot. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extreme binding? No problem.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ItemsDifferenceConverter x:Key="ItemsDifferenceConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Measurements}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Path=Date, StringFormat={}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Counter Gas" Binding="{Binding Path=ValueGas, StringFormat={}{0:F3}}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Difference">
            <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ItemsDifferenceConverter}" Mode="OneWay">
                    <Binding Path="."/>
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}" Path="ItemsSource"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Some kind of converter

```
class ItemsDifferenceConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType,
                      object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length != 2)
            return null;

        var item = values[0] as Measurement;
        var collection = values[1] as IEnumerable<Measurement>;
        if (item == null || collection == null)
            return null;

        var list = collection.OrderBy(v => v.Date).ToList(); //it will be easier to find a previous date
        var itemIndex = list.IndexOf(item);
        if (itemIndex == 0) //First item
            return null;

        var diff = item.ValueGas - list[itemIndex - 1].ValueGas;
        return (diff > 0 ? "+" : "") + diff.ToString();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
    }
}
```

But this example isn't work with removing/updating items of the underlying collection. In this case an intermediate ViewModel is the best choice.

Here is my way to do this. It works with updating, removing and adding items.

```
/// <summary>
/// Main ViewModel, contains items for DataGrid
/// </summary>
public class MeasurementListViewModel
{
    public MeasurementListViewModel(IEnumerable<Measurement> measurements)
    {
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<MeasurementViewModel>(measurements.Select(m=>new MeasurementViewModel(m)));
        this.Measurements = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Items);

        this.Items.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(Items_CollectionChanged);
        foreach(var m in this.Items)
            m.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(Item_PropertyChanged);

    }

    //Date or Value were changed
    void Item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Update the collection view if refresh isn't possible
        if (this.Measurements.IsEditingItem)
            this.Measurements.CommitEdit();
        if (this.Measurements.IsAddingNew)
            this.Measurements.CommitNew();

        this.Measurements.Refresh();
    }

    //Items were added or removed
    void Items_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Attach the observer for the properties
        if (e.NewItems != null)
            foreach (var vm in e.NewItems.OfType<MeasurementViewModel>())
                vm.PropertyChanged += Item_PropertyChanged;

        //Refresh when it is possible
        if(!this.Measurements.IsAddingNew && !this.Measurements.IsEditingItem)
            this.Measurements.Refresh();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MeasurementViewModel> Items { get; set; }

    public ListCollectionView Measurements { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Wraps Measurement class and provide notification of changes
/// </summary>
public class MeasurementViewModel
{
    public MeasurementViewModel()
    {
        this.Model = new Measurement();
    }

    public MeasurementViewModel(Measurement m)
    {
        this.Model = m;
    }

    public Measurement Model { get; private set; }

    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return this.Model.Date; }
        set
        {
            this.Model.Date = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Date");
        }
    }

    public double ValueGas
    {
        get { return this.Model.ValueGas; }
        set
        {
            this.Model.ValueGas = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ValueGas");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

The converter is a bit different:

```
class ItemsDifferenceConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType,
                      object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var item = values[0] as MeasurementViewModel;
        var view = values[1] as ICollectionView;
        if (item == null || view == null)
            return null;

        var list = view.SourceCollection.OfType<MeasurementViewModel>().OrderBy(v => v.Date).ToList(); //it will be easier to find a previous date
        var itemIndex = list.IndexOf(item);

        if (itemIndex == 0) //First item
            return null;

        var diff = item.ValueGas - list[itemIndex - 1].ValueGas;
        return (diff > 0 ? "+" : "") + diff.ToString();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
    }
}
```

And `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Measurements}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          CanUserAddRows="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Path=Date, StringFormat={}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Counter Gas" Binding="{Binding Path=ValueGas, StringFormat={}{0:F3}}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Difference">
            <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ItemsDifferenceConverter}" Mode="OneWay">
                    <Binding Path="."/>
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}" Path="ItemsSource"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works like a charm :) But as you said, there are some drawbacks. But no problem, it's gerate for such a small solution!
Just for interest: How would you implement the intermediate ViewModel in this case?

Comment: @justMe I added my example at the and of the answer. It uses CollectionView and observe changes.

Comment: @vorrtex : how to implement the same View Model in this Scenario ?

I have a datagrid that displays a table from a database vertically as follows :

Scores | 75 | 100

. I have to added a new row called Difference below the Scores which should display or return the difference between the value 75 & 100. (this is just for an example) 

(P.S : No negative values from the difference).. This would be really helpfull.. Thanks

Comment: @Buba1947 If you need a row, not a column, you should add a new item to your collection. Like `someCollection.Add(new SomeModel { Title = "Difference", Score75 = null, Score100 = (scoresItem.Score100 - scoresItem.Score75) });`. Thought it would be better if you make a screenshot of your desired table and make a separate question.

Comment: @vorrtex : I have posted the question in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143637/displaying-the-calculated-information-from-datagrid-to-the-listview-wpf). please have a look when you have time. thank you..